# Extracting information from JSON in ruby without using any gems

Tags: ruby, json, string, hash, rubygems

How do you extract information from JSON format without using any gems? The string is as follows

```
[["B",90461],["B",85547],["B",85709],["B",85029],
["B",85487],["B",83419],["B",83411],["B",85311],["B",81335],
["B",85149],["B",85959]]
```

I need the integer part only and the string can be converted to any types of data. The only requirement is do not use any gems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is not a valid `JSON` object, can you please post the right thing

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the problem with it? Also, could you please be clearer about requirement for "no gems", because `require "json"` and the `JSON` module are available in Ruby standard lib (no gems need be installed)?

Comment: @bjhaid - It's valid JSON

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby's stdib [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) for the same :

```
require 'json'

a = '[["B",90461],["B",85547],["B",85709],["B",85029],
["B",85487],["B",83419],["B",83411],["B",85311],["B",81335],
["B",85149],["B",85959]]'

JSON.parse(a).map(&:last)
# => [90461,
#     85547,
#     85709,
#     85029,
#     85487,
#     83419,
#     83411,
#     85311,
#     81335,
#     85149,
#     85959]
```

Also look at this method : [`JSON::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) .

Comment: I realized that the OP says that the requirement is not to use a gem, and "json" is a gem.

Answer (score 1):

```
'[["B",90461],["B",85547],["B",85709],["B",85029], ["B",85487],["B",83419],["B",83411],["B",85311],["B",81335], ["B",85149],["B",85959]]'
.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
# => => [90461, 85547, 85709, 85029, 85487, 83419, 83411, 85311, 81335, 85149, 85959]
```

Answer (score 1):

Working from these assumptions:

- for some reason, you can't simply use Ruby's stdlib JSON library, as suggested by many others
- the `"B"` strings in your incoming data may be replaced by any other single valid JSON object, however complex; e.g. `{ "key1": ["ABC", { "key2": "{\"key3\": [\"DEF\"]}" }]}`
- you want only and exactly the second values (always integers) of arrays nested one level deep in a top-level array; e.g. `[[..., 123], [..., 456]]` yields `[123, 456]`

Here is your function:

```
def parse_integers_from_specific_JSON (string)
  ary_depth = 0     # Level of nesting within arrays
  obj_depth = 0     # Level of nesting within objects
  in_string = false # Flag for whether the parser is inside a string
  escaped = false   # Flag for whether the next character will be escaped
  int_buffer = ""   # String buffer for integer digits
  integers = []     # Result array of integers

  string.each_char do |c|
    if (in_string) && !(escaped) && (c == '\\')
      # When an escape character is found in a string, set the 'escaped' flag
      escaped = true
      next
    end

    if (c == '"')
      if !in_string
        # When a quote is found outside a string, enter the new string
        in_string = true

      elsif escaped
        # When an escaped quote is found within a string, ignore it

      else
        # When an unescaped quote is found within a string, exit the string
        in_string = false
      end
    end

    # If relevant, the 'escaped' flag has escaped its quote by now; unset it
    escaped = false

    if !(in_string) && (c =~ /\d/) && (obj_depth == 0) && (ary_depth == 2)
      # If a digit is encountered at the correctly nested position,
      # append it to the integer buffer string
      int_buffer << c

    elsif !(int_buffer.empty?)
      # If the integer buffer string has digits in it and the current character
      # is not a digit, flush the contents of the buffer into the result array
      integers << int_buffer.to_i
      int_buffer.clear
    end

    unless in_string
      # Check for unquoted special characters and adjust depth
      case c
      when '{' then obj_depth += 1
      when '}' then obj_depth -= 1
      when '[' then ary_depth += 1
      when ']' then ary_depth -= 1
      end
    end
  end

  return integers
end
```

Here's a snippet showing it in action, using a beefed-up version of your sample data:

```
incoming_data_string = (<<-JSON).strip
[
  ["B",90461],
  [[],85547],
  [["A"],85709],
  ["",85029],
  [[123,456],85487],
  [[456,[789],"A"],83419],
  [{ a: [123] },83411],
  ["B",85311],
  ["B",81335],
  ["B",85149],
  [{ "key1": ["ABC", { "key2": "{\\"key3\\": [\\"DEF\\"]}" }]},85959]
]
JSON

p parse_integers_from_specific_JSON(incoming_data_string)

#=> [90461, 85547, 85709, 85029, 85487, 83419, 83411, 85311, 81335, 85149, 85959]
```

This won't be particularly fast. If you want it to be fast, the correct answer is to `require 'json'` and use `JSON::parse`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a json module in standard library ([link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)).

Also simple  solution without parsing (but with eval, which is evil):

```
eval('[["B",111111],["B",222222],["B",333333]]').map(&:last)
```

Comment: don't teach people to use `eval` avoid it when you can as almost everytime you use it, there is a safer alternative

Comment: @bjhaid You sound like a parrot repeating another person's words without thinking what they mean. Why are data with pairs of alphabet string and a numeral not safe?

Comment: @sawa this is a json object most likely received from an external service that you cannot be certain of what it's content would always be, I am not repeating anyone's word but sure of what I am saying, and most times eval is used there is a safer alternative